# iOS app: Checking for internet connection only works for WLAN, not for mobil data

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, internet-connection

I'm using this to check for Internet connection in my iOS app made with  Swift: [TUTORIAL: CHECK FOR INTERNET CONNECTION IN SWIFT](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-check-for-internet-connection-in-swift/)

But it seems only to work for WLAN, not for mobile data.

Before I start troubleshooting in other ways: Does anybody know whether this code should work for mobile data, too? Am I doing something wrong or is this code not for checking for internet connection when using mobile data?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the author of this article. This code doesn't work for mobile data/cellular/3G.

**It only works for Wi-Fi/WLAN.**

Here's a working example for Wi-Fi **and** Cellular: [`Reachability_Swift`](http://www.filedropper.com/reachabilityswift2)